# Change radiobutton multiple times using jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I can't seem to change between radio buttons correctly using jQuery. Is this a bug in jQuery? Example here: http://jsbin.com/yafik/1/edit

Code from jsbin:

```
<input type="radio" name="test">
<input type="radio" name="test">
<input type="radio" name="test">
<input type="radio" name="test">

<script>
    $("input").eq(1).attr("checked", true);
    $("input").eq(2).attr("checked", true);
    //$("input").attr("checked", false);
    $("input").eq(1).attr("checked", true);
</script>
```

You can also try to uncomment the third line: `$("input").attr("checked", false);`, which I'd expect to just reset all checked attributes.

I would expect it to set the second radiobutton to checked. But if you look at the source code, both the second and third radiobuttons are actually checked.

Comment: Put your code here. JSBin is not a substitution. And Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Your jsBin works as expected, so what are you expecting???

Comment: @A.Wolff What browser are you using? It doesn't work in Chrome. Seems to be working in Firefox, though.

Comment: @peirix on chrome too, works for me as expected, only second radio button is checked

Comment: See also : [Properties and attributes in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for boolean values

```
$("input").eq(1).prop("checked", true);
$("input").eq(2).prop("checked", true);
$("input").eq(1).prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Wow. Never even heard of that one before. Good to know.

Comment: @peirix BUT that's what is used in your linked jsBin! That's quite confusing to say the least...

Comment: @peirix Something strange happen, wasn't it your former posted link: http://jsbin.com/xoruxoxo/1/edit ??? I guess i'm missing something

Comment: @A.Wolff Nope, my jsbin id was `yafik`, not `xoruxoxo`.

Comment: @peirix that was the link i clicked before you edited your post